# html select is off center when the page is loaded

Tags: html, freemarker

i have a select on my page, and when the page loads the text that is initially displayed in the select box is not in the right spot, it is shifted down slightly. has anyone heard of this or seen this problem. this is what my select looks like

```
<select id="usersearches">
        <#if search??>
            <#list search as s>
                <option value="${s.id!}" <#if response.payload.title?? && response.payload.title == s.title!> selected="selected" </#if> id="${s.id!}" query="${s.query!}">${s.title!}</option>
            </#list>
        </#if>
    </select>
```

i am using freemarker for my client side stuff, to select the option that needs to be selected. this only happens when the page is first loaded, once i click on the selectbox the text fixes it self, even if i dont select a new option. more information is that the options will trigger a page redirect. all help and ideas are welcome and appreciated.
I forgot to add that this occurs in IE8 (or IE in general)

Code:

```
$("#usersearches").change(function(){
    var which = "#"+$(this).val();
    var url = "${orderSearchPostURL}?"+$(which).attr("query")+"&_title="+$(which).html()+"&sea‌​rchType="+$(this).val();
window.location.href=url;
});
```

Comment: Please show the resulting HTML + CSS. Your server-side code is not helpful in (and actually deters from) solving this issue.

Comment: that is all the html. just that selectbox, there is no css style applied to this html

Comment: '$("#usersearches").change(function(){
 var which = "#"+$(this).val();

 var url = "${orderSearchPostURL}?"+$(which).attr("query")+"&_title="+$(which).html()+"&searchType="+$(this).val();
 window.location.href=url;
});'
This jquery is the only thing that goes with the selectbox

Comment: from your html page, right-click, show source, and paste the generated select please